# Execute query with parameter work incorrect

Tags: c#, oracle

I have Student table with two field(id: number, name: 10 char)
The example value of name column is: 'William[2 space]', 'Ethan[5 space]'
(The space will be add to meet the max length)

The queries below work fine. (hard code or string interpolation)

```
 select * from where name = 'William'
or select * from where name = 'William  '
```

But when i use parameter like below, it doesn't work

```
select * from where name = :Name

and then inject the parameters
var result = ctx.ExecuteStatement(query, new { Name = name })

So when name = 'William  ', it work.
But when name = 'William', it doesn't work.
```

=> I want it work in two case? Please help me address the issue.

So my temporary solution is trim the column before compare. But i think it just work around and not completely resolve the problem since oracle automatically ignore the whitespace(I showed in my first sample)

```
select * from where trim(name) = :Name
```

Comment: Why are you storing data in the DB with trailing spaces?  Max length sounds like it is a business rule that should be enforced by the business layer, not the DB layer.

Comment: @jason.kaisersmith The old system using c++ and work fine without trim(). But when I convert to c# but keep the same database, it doesn't work. In my thought, it's the library issue or i did wrong somewhere

Answer (score 2):

do not use `char` as datatype to store strings with variable length. use `varchar2` instead

Comment: if you don't want to use work arounds like `trim`, `rpad` or so on, fix the datatype problem.

Comment: I just wonder why it works without parameters. There is a bug in Oracle database access library

Comment: i would say it's not a bug, the select statement is just executed in different context. so Oracle can not make it to char(10).  if you do a select  in your ide you are using SQL engine. if you put your select as string, I can imagine that this select is executed as dynamic SQL in plsql engine.

Answer (score 1):

You could add whitespaces by

> ```
> name = name.PadRight(10);
> ```

PadRight aligns the text to the left and fills the string with whitespaces to obtain the defined length.